# How to listen for Slimscroll "scroll" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

Basically I want to run some stuff whenever the user scrolls... how could I possibly do that?

I already know about this event which I found on SlimScroll website, but there is no other events other than this one;

```
//...

var $scrollable = $('.scrollable');

$scrollable.slimScroll().bind('slimscroll', function (e, pos) {
    // SOME CODE...
});

//...
```

But this only works when the scrollbar reaches either top or bottom of the scrollable section.

The scrollbar itself works fine, just need an event listener!

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, after looking into the slimscroll unminified version I spotted this "**slimscrolling**" event listener, so I simply replaced this with "**slimscroll**" and things worked as I wanted!

So simply run this code;

```
//...

var $scrollable = $('.scrollable');

$scrollable.slimScroll().bind('slimscrolling', function (e, pos) {
    // SOME CODE...
});

//...
```

Hope this saves your time as I spent ages figuring this out :)
Thanks

Comment: I know this is too old, but I wanted to know if we can detect the direction of scroll (scroll to top or to down ) ?

Comment: @pietà This isn't something that SlimScroll offers but I've made one for you on Codepen https://codepen.io/stylish/pen/KZXeJG?editors=0010
Make sure you open your console (alt + cmd + j) Regards

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:-

For those of you that asked me either privately or here on how you could possibly track the SlimScroll's scroll direction (UP or DOWN)!

The bad news is this isn't something that SlimScroll offers as of yet, however on the other side, the good news is I've been able to put together a little snippet that does the job for you!

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/stylish/pen/KZXeJG?editors=0011)
```

Hope it helps :)
Thanks